Custom page: trigger createRoute on size changes
I am using go_router and go_router_builder. I have a page that on small screens is shown as a DraggableScrollableBottomSheet, and on wider screen a custom implementation of Material 3's side sheets. The relevant code is as follows:
class TokenDetailsRoute extends GoRouteData {
  TokenDetailsRoute({required this.id});

  final String id;

  @override
  Page buildPage(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const DetailsPage(child: TokenDetails());
  }
}

class DetailsPage<T> extends Page<T> {
  const DetailsPage({required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Route<T> createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    final isWide = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600;
    if (!isWide) {
      return ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
        settings: this,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.9,
            minChildSize: 0.5,
            maxChildSize: 0.9,
            expand: false,
            builder: (context, scrollController) => child,
          );
        },
      );
    }
    return RawDialogRoute<T>(
      settings: this,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      ) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(1, 0),
                  end: Offset.zero,
                )
                    .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOutCubic))
                    .animate(animation),
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                  ),
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

In the createRoute function, I check if the screen is wide with a MediaQuery. This works fine. However, if I navigate to this page on a small screen (triggering the bottomsheet) and consequently change the screen to a large screen (by making the browser tab bigger, for example), the bottomsheet does not get replaced by the sidesheet once the 600 threshold is met. How can I listen for these changes?
